# In OfficeJS if we use the addFileAttachmentAsync function for multiple files, the callback runs only for one

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

The basic implementation of the `addFileAttachmentAsync` is as follows:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
  fileURL,
  selectedAttachment.name,
  {},
  (result) => {
    console.log('error or success')
  },
);
```

Now this works. If I call this multiple times for multiple files, it works. All the files get uploaded. But one problem. The callback gets fired only once. Let's say there were two files and both files throw errors. I'll be able to read the error of only one file. How can I fix this and make the callback run for all executions separately?

Comment: Are you making each subsequent addFileAttachmentAsync call in the callback of the previous addFileAttachmentAsync call? Basically, are you nesting the calls?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT No, I'm not nesting the calls.

Comment: That would explain the issue you are observing. Since each call is async, you should nest them. Can you nest the calls and try to see if you still encounter this issue?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Investigating more into this, nesting shouldn't be required. I was able to repro this in Outlook Web Access (the web client) but not the Desktop Client. Can you confirm you were also seeing the bug only in the Web Client?